# What are the relative market shares of the various Apple-related package managers?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, carthage, swift-package-manager

Our open source library is used by developers on all Apple platforms: iOS, macOS, tvOS and watchOS.  An issue has arisen with its Carthage deployment on tvOS and I've been asked what the impact for users is.  We know how many deployments on each platform we have; what we don't know is *how* our library is being deployed.

Are there any figures - historical or current - on the relative uptake of each of the three main package managers, [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/), [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) and [Swift Package Manager](https://swift.org/package-manager/)?

Note: I'm *not* interested in the relative merits of each.  This is *not* a "which one is better" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://iosdevsurvey.com/2019/12-dependency-management/, for 2019:

For business apps:

- CocoaPods 74.8%
- Carthage 26.4%
- Swift Package Manager 17.8%

For personal apps:

- CocoaPods 68.3%
- Carthage 25.4%
- Swift Package Manager 35.5%

[Edit: [2020 figures can be found here](https://iosdevsurvey.com/2020/09-dependency-management/)]

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks, and a really useful link to the source.